# KeyError: 'irrelevant' In dictionary while sentiment analysis using Naive and SVM

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, sentiment-analysis, naivebayes

I am doing Sentiment analysis using Naive bays and SVM, 
i refered this code https://github.com/sravyaysk/MyProjects/blob/master/SentimentAnalysis.py

I converted this implementation in python 3, Here is code to implement it assigns positive as 1 and negative as 2, I added neutral as 3 but it still return's error as irrelevant

My code's and dataset
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1NiZC7DNOkzpUFZ1X6PjD2rrn99TGXnkL?usp=sharing

this is the part of code where I am getting error: SVM.py

```
labels_to_array={"positive":1,"negative":2}
labels=[labels_to_array[tweet[1]] for tweet in ppTrainingData]
y=np.array(labels)
```

ERROR:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-11-d1d8945f9453> in <module>
        161 # Lets map positive to 1 and negative to 2 so that everything is nicely represented as arrays
        162 labels_to_array={"neutral":1,"negative":2,"positive":3}
    --> 163 labels=[labels_to_array[tweet[1]] for tweet in ppTrainingData]
        164 y=np.array(labels)
        165 

    <ipython-input-11-d1d8945f9453> in <listcomp>(.0)
        161 # Lets map positive to 1 and negative to 2 so that everything is nicely represented as arrays
        162 labels_to_array={"neutral":1,"negative":2,"positive":3}
    --> 163 labels=[labels_to_array[tweet[1]] for tweet in ppTrainingData]
        164 y=np.array(labels)
        165
 KeyError: 'neutral'
```

Comment: Hi, you need to post the relevant code you wrote and the full error message in the question.  Don't ask people to click on external links and to read long code.

Comment: Do you have "neutral" in the labels_to_array dictionary or not?  In the code you posted you don't have it, but in the error message you do.  KeyError means that Python can't find that key.

Comment: @AlexK yes in the dictionary i have added this label , when I remove  "neutral" label it returns keyerror : neutral and if i add back into dictionary it returns key error:"irrelevant"

Comment: So then you need to add "irrelevant" to that labels_to_array dictionary, because Python is complaining that it can't find that key.